# Python script is causing time drift

Tags: python, datetime, raspberry-pi

I have the following Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import time
import serial
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import os.path

PATH = '/home/pi/test/'
Y = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y')[3]

def get_current_time():
    return datetime.datetime.now()


def get_current_time_f1():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')


def get_current_time_f2():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


def compare_time():
    current_time = get_current_time()
    if current_time.minute == 59 and current_time.second >= 45:
        return "new"


def file_date():
    if compare_time() == "new":
    plusonehour = datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)
    return plusonehour.strftime('Z'+Y+'%m%d%H')
else:
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('Z'+Y+'%m%d%H')


def createCeilFile():
    filename = os.path.join(PATH, file_date()+".dat")
    fid = open(filename, "w")
    fid.writelines(["-Ceilometer Logfile","\n","-File created: "+get_current_time_f1(),"\n"])
    return fid


# open the first file at program start
fid = createCeilFile()

# serial port settings
ser=serial.Serial(
   port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
   baudrate = 19200,
   parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
   stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
   bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
)
counter=0

# read first byte, grab date string, read rest of string, print both in file
while 1: 
  tdata = ser.read()
  time.sleep(3)
  data_left = ser.inWaiting()
  tdata += ser.read(data_left)
  fid.writelines(["-"+get_current_time_f2(),"\n",tdata,"\n"])

  #should have ~10 secs before next message needs to come in
  #if next string will go into the next hour
  if compare_time() == "new":
      # close old file
      fid.writelines(["File closed: "+get_current_time_f2(),"\n"])
      fid.close()

      # open new file
      fid = createCeilFile()

      # then it goes back to 'tdata = ser.read()' and waits again.
```

It works fine and stores all the data I need in the correct format and so on.

A data message from the device comes trough every 15 seconds. The python script runs for an infinite time and reads those messages. At the beginning of each message the script adds a time, when the message was written to the file and therefor received. And the time is the problem with this script. I have a time drift of about 3 to 4 seconds in 24 hours. Weird about that is, that the time drifts backwards. So if I start with data messages coming in at 11, 26, 41 and 56 seconds during the minute, after 24 hours the messages seem to come in at 8, 23, 38 and 53 seconds in the minute.

Has anyone an explanation for that or maybe a way to compensate it? I thought about restarting the program every hour, after it saved the hourly file. Maybe that helps resetting the weird time drift?

Comment: The raspberry-pi does not have a real time clock, so will naturally drift quite a bit. Do you have internet access to be able to resync using an ntp server?

Comment: Yeah the Pi synchronizes over the internet once an hour. Where is the answer that was here before saying that the `sleep` command could be the issue?